Dropbox Desktop App and Marking Files as Online-Only
I would like to use dropbox to backup my files to the cloud, but do not have enough storage space on my hard drive for everything in my dropbox account. I read on the dropbox website that I can mark files as "online only", but to do this I need to go into the dropbox desktop app.
I installed the .deb package for Ubuntu 22.10 or higher. I have Ubuntu 24.04.1. There is now a dropbox icon, but when I click on it, nothing happens. Does the desktop app exist, or is dropbox just managed through the terminal?
How do I mark files as online only so that they don't take up storage space on my hard drive but I can still access them on my computer and not have to login to dropbox online. Is this possible?

You might be interested in reading this topic on Dropbox Community which addresses this issue.

further, you may be interested in this itsFOSS article on how to install Dropbox. Pay particular attention to step 4 which also relates to selective sync

Try with rclone: ​​https://rclone.org/dropbox/

A disappointing answer may be better than no answer at all.
The option to have files only in on-line storage is only available on the desktop app. As the help page also states: "The system requirements for using online-only files are: Windows: 7 and higher, and Mac: OS 10.12 and higher."

Rclone is a tool to manage data in the cloud efficiently and securely on Linux systems
Open a terminal.
Run in it:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rclone

Configure the application with the following command in the same terminal:
rclone config

Select the option to add a new remote, select “n” and press Enter.
Choose a name to be used to refer to your Dropbox connection in rclone, for example Dropbox
Select the type of storage you will use, Dropbox corresponds (??) to drive Dropbox and press Enter.
Configure the Dropbox application, follow the instructions that appear in the terminal to obtain the authorization token, which will allow you to access your Dropbox from rclone.
Select the default configuration settings, which are suitable.
Once the configuration is complete, it will show you a summary of your options, if everything is correct, confirm the configuration.
Create the directory where to mount Dropbox, for example ~/dropbox, by running in the terminal
mkdir dropbox

To access Dropbox, you must run the following command in a terminal:
rclone mount Dropbox: ~/dropbox &

You can create a script to run this command when you start your computer and always have Dropbox mounted on your system, if you want.
